# How can I exclude words with apostrophes when reading into a table of strings?

Tags: c++, string, file-io

```
ifstream fin;
    string temp;
    fin.open("engldict.txt");
    if(fin.is_open())
    {
        bool apos = false;
        while(!fin.eof())
        {
            getline(fin, temp, '\n');
            if(temp.length() > 2 && temp.length() < 7)
            {
                for(unsigned int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++)
                {
                    if(temp.c_str()[i] == '\'')
                        apos = true;
                }

                if(!apos)
                    dictionary.insert(temp);
            }
        }
    }
```

This code gives me a runtime error: Unhandled exception at 0x00A50606 in Word Jumble.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000014.

and throws me a break point at:

```
size_type size() const _NOEXCEPT
        {   // return length of sequence
        return (this->_Mysize);
        }
```

within the xstring header.

This exception is thrown no matter what character I use, so long as it is present within the words I am reading in.

I am aware that it is probably a super simple fix, but I just really need another set of eyes to see it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can see several errors, but none that would cause that crash. Are you sure this is the code that causes the crash?

Comment: This won't cause your crash but note that you need to set `apos=false` for each iteration of your `while` loop.

Comment: FWIW `while(!fin.eof()) { getline(fin, temp, '\n');` should be `while(getline(fin, temp, '\n')) {`, and `temp.c_str()[i]` is better written as `temp[i]` and simonc has already mentioned the other error.

Comment: positively, it only crashes when I compare temp.c_str()[i] to a character that would be present. If I use another char (such as a comma) everything runs fine, I just have to deal with apostrophes.

Comment: @rearden But does it crash *in this code*? I'm guessing not and that you also have another bug later in your code. A bug that only manifests itself when you add this code (which is also bugged).